# Reading multiple files with QFile

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, multiple-file-upload

I want to read multiple files. I get en error in `QFile` because it reads only one file at once.

- How can I solve this problem?
- And how can I iterate my files and use them.

```cpp
QStringList fileNames;
fileNames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this,
  tr("choose"),
  "up.sakla",
  tr("choosen(*.up)"));

if (fileNames.isEmpty())
  return;

QFile file(fileNames);
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream in ( & file);
QString str;
qint32 a; in >> str >> a;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you have some files within a folder and you would like to read a list of files (the ones that you selected through the `QFileDialog`)

Here is the complete code:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
   
    QStringList fileNames;



    fileNames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(nullptr, "choose", "up.sakla", "choosen(*.up)");

    for (auto xfile : fileNames)
    {
        QFile file (xfile);
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QTextStream in(&file);
        QString str;
        while (!in.atEnd())
        {
           //read all the file content as a text
           str = in.readAll();
           qDebug() << str;
        }


    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

If the contents of each file is the following:

- file 1 content

```
File1 11
```

- file 2 content

```
File1 12
```

- file 3 content

```
File1 13
```

The output of the program would be as follows:

```sh
"File3 13\n \n"
"File1 11\n \n"
"File2 12\n \n"
```

Comment: Thank you. It works and solve my problem.

Comment: Hi. I want to some operations after selection. But my code do it for just one file. how should I write a loop for it? 

Do something, for every file ı choose

Comment: you do in in the while loop. It will be done for every file.

Comment: @Pat.ANDRIA if I just have a couple QFiles I want to read, can I do it without using a loop? How does one reference multiple QFiles?

Answer (score 1):

as you can see in th official do [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileNames)

> This is a convenience static function that will return one or more existing files selected by the user.

on the other hand QFile constructor is not accepting that QStringList([doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html))

[image]

what you can do is loop over every element on the list

```
for(auto x : fileNames)
{
    QFile file(x);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QDataStream in(&file);   
    QString str;
    qint32 a;
    in >> str >> a;
}
```